# Align vertical Item according vh to all resolutions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a few elements working as layers(all absolute positioned and with z-index).

The major problem is, I have one image that should be placed at the **bottom 0 of my Viewport Height(vh)**

I already tried bottom positioning, vertical align and translate, and the solutions sometime works but only on my native resolution, when I start to test in responsive they got messed up! (even when I use % of positioning).

[image: force bottom positioning without using height]

Here's my last shot:

```
    <div className={`${styles.personWrapper} hidden-xs hidden-sm`}>
      <div className={styles.personPositioning}>
        <img src={person} className={styles.person} alt="person" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.personWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 91;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.personPositioning {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.person {
  width: 43.4%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 60;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 0.1s 2.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  bottom: -10px;
  // transform: translate(58%,22%);
}
```

Other tries:

```
.personWrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 91;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.personPositioning {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.person {
  width: 43.4%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 60;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadein 0.1s 2.4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  bottom: -10px;
  // transform: translate(58%,22%);
}
```

Comment: Did you try fixed position?

Comment: i can't use fixed position the image will just appear during the first section @Axnyff

Comment: Use flex and set image to margin-top: auto

Comment: can you add code snippets so we can test different solutions

Comment: @ChrisRosenlind flexbox doesn't work with z-index

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: looks like person wrapper is not 100% the size of the viewport

Comment: @Pete I already tried using 100% of the viewport and inserting background transparent to "up" the other div(the right background) and occupy the space without success

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I've filled the whole wrapper div and the div that dropped I've used top: -50vh in the next div.

```
   <div className={`${styles.personWrapper} hidden-xs hidden-sm`}>
      <div className={styles.personPositioning}>
        <img src={person} className={styles.person} alt="person" />
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className={styles.anotherDiv}>
    content
   </div>
```

---

```
.personWrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 91;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.personPositioning {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.person {
 width: 43.4%;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 60;
 opacity: 0;
 animation: fadein 0.1s 2.4s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 25%;
}

.anotherDiv {
   top: -50vh;
}
```